# How to shutdown Linux parted magic from terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, shutdown, parted-magic

Once in a while I have to use parted magic to restore superblocks. I tried to execute in the terminal:

```
shutdown -h now
telinit 0
```

Both did not work,
what else might be possible to shutdown Linux via command line?

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute the following command as root:

```
halt
```